# Check List Box style Radio Button list

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is it possible to have a Radio button list, like we have a checked List box?
Actually I want to load all the options from database to the list but do not want user to allow to check more than one item.

Also how to read it (say item 4 of the list)  I want to store its value in the variable.

Thanks and best regards.
Furqan

Comment: Is it an ASP.Net Web-Application?

Comment: VB.Net is only the language and not the technology(like ASP.Net or Windows Forms). Ok, then see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the ASP.Net RadioButtonList-Control try this example:

aspx(you can configure the datasource on the designer(show smart Tag):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
     DataTextField="ClaimStatusName" DataValueField="idClaimStatus">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RM2ConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [idClaimStatus], [ClaimStatusName] FROM [dimClaimStatus]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

A Radiobuttonlist allows user to select only  one item by default.
The selected Item is stored in `RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem`.

**EDIT**: As you have clairified now that it's a Winform issue, you need a [GroupBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx) to allow user only to select one.

To create the Radiobuttons dynamically from datasource and add them to the Groupbox, have a look at my samplecode:

```
    Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim allStatus As DataSet2.StatusDataTable = New DataSet2TableAdapters.StatusTableAdapter().GetData()
        For i As Int32 = 0 To allStatus.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim status As DataSet2.StatusRow = allStatus(i)
            Dim rb As New RadioButton()
            rb.Text = status.ClaimStatusName
            rb.Tag = status.idClaimStatus
            rb.Location = New Point(Me.GroupBox1.Location.X + 5, Me.GroupBox1.Location.Y + i * rb.Height)
            AddHandler rb.CheckedChanged, AddressOf RBCheckedChanged
            Me.GroupBox1.Controls.Add(rb)
        Next
        Me.GroupBox1.Visible = allStatus.Rows.Count > 0
        If allStatus.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim width, height As Int32
            Dim lastRB As Control = Me.GroupBox1.Controls(GroupBox1.Controls.Count - 1)
            width = lastRB.Width + 20
            height = lastRB.Height
            Me.GroupBox1.Size = New Size(width, allStatus.Rows.Count * height + 20)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RBCheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim source As RadioButton = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)
        Dim checkedRB As RadioButton = getCheckedRadioButton(Me.GroupBox1)
        'source and checkedRB are the same objetcs because we are in CheckedChanged-Event'
        'but getCheckedRadioButton-function works from everywhere'
    End Sub

    Private Function getCheckedRadioButton(ByVal group As GroupBox) As RadioButton
        For Each ctrl As Control In group.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButton Then
                If DirectCast(ctrl, RadioButton).Checked Then Return DirectCast(ctrl, RadioButton)
            End If
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Remember that you must replace my data objects with yours.

Comment: Sorry, I donot need it in asp.  I need it in winforms